# How to get X and Y coordinate values of the map?

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, c#, coordinates

I want the `upper right` and `lower left` *coordinate* of the exposed portion of the map, and for the whole map.

What is the way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast the Map to [IActiveView](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/IActiveView_Interface/001200000199000000/). You can then access the [Extent](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0012000001mz000000) and [FullExtent](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0012000001n2000000) properties, which will give you the desired information.

Comment: Didn't testing it yet, but seems right thanks a lot.