# Exporting xy-coordinates from line segment

Tags: qgis, line, coordinates, export, xy

I need an export of xy-coordinates of line segments in QGIS. I found an answer to a similar question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63301/how-to-export-x-y-coordinates-from-geodata) but that concerned only xy of the first and last vertex of a line segment. But I need the coordinates of all the vertexes. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

The `Geometry Export To CSV` part of the mmqgis plugin enables you to export the node coordinates into a csv file.

This page should give you some hints on how to use the plugin:

http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/

Answer (score 1):

There's a tool in the open source GIS Whitebox Geospatial Analysis Tools (http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/) called 'Extract Nodes'. It does exactly what you are looking for. It takes a shapefile of polylines or polygons and returns a vector of the node points.

[image]

Comment: To the down-voter, why would you downvote this answer? It solves the OP's question. It describes a tool that can take a shapefile of polylines and outputs a shapefile of node points. That's exactly what they are looking for. I'm really starting to think that I need to abandon GIS stack exchange.

Comment: I did not downvote your answer, but the asker wanted to do it with Quantum GIS. Don't bother about someone not liking your answer, though. It might be useful to someone.

Comment: @AndreJoost, Thank you for your comment. Just because a poster specifies a specific software package though doesn't mean that they wouldn't be willing to try a different tool if it solves their problem in a more straightforward way. It's usually, though not always, the problem that is more important than the software. If this isn't the case then we've failed to educate GIS users to be spatial problem solvers rather than button pushers. I like to think that's not the case.

Comment: @AndreJoost

Is there a way to extract the same end coordinates of a line using Python? Considering I have a PolyLine shapefile?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you out with Python code. Maybe you put this a s a separate question, asking for a Python solution.

Comment: The Whitebox Tools are now accessible through QGIS, although I've had some issues with the ExtractNodes function

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following related answered questions:

- [How to export Polygons to CSV with coordinates?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23376/how-to-export-polygons-to-csv-with-coordinates?rq=1)
- [Getting list of coordinates for points in layer using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8844/get-list-of-coordinates-for-points-in-a-layer/8911#8911)
- [QGIS 3x capturing coordinates for multitude of objects at once](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/373187/qgis-3x-capturing-coordinates-for-multitude-of-objects-at-once)

If those don't work for you, please provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

A Greek way:
A) Select the feature you want, copy it and paste onto a word processor.
B) delete the first part `wkt_geom…` and the parenthesis at the end so there are only numbers.
C) Replace: `,`  (comma and one space) with `^p` (MS word) or `\n` (Libre office-Open office).
D) replace one space with comma. You get the list of coordinates in the X,Y format.

Answer (score 1):

Use extract nodes.  From line to points => saved in shape file. Then save the point shape file  in save as vector layer window as csv. In the layer option, change the following : create csvt = yes, geometry = as xy, separator = comma. Check the extent (current layer). Supply the file name, then click OK.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the `Extract vertices` function to create a point shapefile of the vertices. The properties of the line (such as ID) will be retained for later reference
2. Add the xy geometry properties in any number of ways, perhaps with the Attribute Table field calculator to add attributes named xx and yy with $x and $y in the calculation, or simply the `Add X/Y fields to layer` function, or other means.
3. Export the points layer as a CSV format (if needed, or whatever format you want).

Answer (score 0):

In fact we do not need any plugin or special function to extract vertices from linestrings or polygons. Simply create a memory point layer (see link), copy your selected features to this layer and open the attribute table to copy the vertices to the clipboard. BTW you can always set the point layer to a different CRS if you like, coordinates are transformed automatically. For more see: [Programmatically extract edge points from many polygons?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/289710/programmatically-extract-edge-points-from-many-polygons/370813#370813)