# Programmatically extract edge points from many polygons?

Tags: qgis, polygon, coordinates, mgrs, point

**Objective**: Extract the four Latitude, Longitude points which correspond to the corner edges of each polygon in the Military Grid Reference System (MGRS) shapefile.

**How can this be done in QGIS?**

In this picture the red arrows point to the places I would like to know the Latitude, Longitude:
[image]

Here is what the MGRS shapefiles look like in QGIS 2.8.16, notice the corners look good:
[image]

When I used:
y_min(bounds($geometry))
x_min(bounds($geometry))
y_max(bounds($geometry))
x_max(bounds($geometry))

And then plotted the data in Tableau Desktop, the result is some of the polygons are overlapping slightly and the corners aren't matching up exactly.
[image]

**Here are the points which make up 14SPC:**

GZD,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,MGRS,PointID
14S,32.519328,-97.93512,14SPB,1
14S,33.434729,-99,14SNC,1
14S,33.420739,-97.924236,14SPC,1
14S,33.403103,-96.848967,14SQC,1
14S,34.322005,-97.912856,14SPD,1
14S,33.434729,-97.93512,14SPB,2
14S,34.341303,-99,14SNC,2
14S,34.336476,-97.924236,14SPC,2
14S,34.322005,-96.848967,14SQC,2
14S,35.238088,-97.912856,14SPD,2
14S,33.434729,-96.848967,14SPB,3
14S,34.341303,-97.912856,14SNC,3
14S,34.336476,-96.826229,14SPC,3
14S,34.322005,-96,14SQC,3
14S,35.238088,-96.802458,14SPD,3
14S,32.519328,-96.848967,14SPB,4
14S,33.434729,-97.912856,14SNC,4
14S,33.420739,-96.826229,14SPC,4
14S,33.403103,-96,14SQC,4
14S,34.322005,-96.802458,14SPD,4

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: After days of Googling and trying to find a way in both QGIS and ArcDesktop, I wasn't finding anything that was helpful. If I had something that was sort of working or worth posting I would have posted it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the field calculator to add this values to the attribute table of the layer (may be a virtual field is the best, because this values are recalculated when opening the attribute table).

Open the attribute table of your layer and select field calculator (the abacus icon):

[image: expression for x_max]

Similar way you can create x_min, y_min and y_max. You can find the *bound* and *x_max*, *y_max*, *x_min*, *y_min* functions in the geometry group.

Answer (score 2):

In QGIS, use the tool `Extract Vertices` to convert the vertices of your polygon layer to points. Make sure to save this layer in a geographic coordinate system.

You can view the coordinates of each point by clicking on it with the `Identify` tool.

To extract all the coordinates as a table, use the `Field Calculator` to add X and Y fields. Then save the vertices layer in CSV format. Now you have a CSV file that you can open with Excel.

Comment: In QGIS 2.8.16, do I need to install a plugin to use the Extract Vertices tool? I don't see it when I look in my menu drop downs.

Comment: I have no idea. You didn't specify a version of QGIS, so I assumed you were using a recent one.

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS 3.x you can make use of side effects to extract edge points from polygons, when you copy&paste features from your polygon layer to a memory point layer:

```py
layer = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=epsg:4326&field=name:string(255)", "nodes", "memory")
layer.addExpressionField( '$x', QgsField( 'x', QVariant.Double) )
layer.addExpressionField( '$y', QgsField( 'y', QVariant.Double) )
layer.addExpressionField( '$id - minimum( $id,group_by:="name") + 1', QgsField( 'id', QVariant.Int) )
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers([layer])
```

The edge point Ids are autoicremented and start at 1 for every polygon.
The big benefit is: you can always change the CRS of the memory layer before you copy the polygons.